# Scraping data from website with frames in android studio

Tags: javascript, android, web, frame, scrape

I am trying to scrape data from a website with framesets and frames to an Android application in Android Studio.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>


</head>

<!-- frames -->
<frameset  rows="32,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame name="frMenu" src="Sestava_pro_web_menu.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="5" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" noresize>
    <frame name="frObsah"  marginwidth="10" marginheight="2" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no">
</frameset>

</html>
```

It's working with Selenium and Puppeteer, but I don't know how to execute it in an Android project. Could you help or tell me some other way to do it? I am desperate.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async ()=>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.sps-tabor.cz/rozvrh-supl/Sestava_pro_web.html");

    const frame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.name() === 'frObsah');
    //const text = await frame.$eval('document.querySelector("#post-13008 > div > div > div > div > p")', element => element.textContent);
    //const text = document.querySelector("#post-13008 > div > div > div > div > p");
    const texts = await frame.$$eval("tr",els => els.map(el => el.innerText));
    //const text = await frame.content();
    texts.forEach(text => console.log(text));

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Then, I also want to structure data into a table.